# Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true paralyzes api response

Tags: laravel, api, nuxt.js, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have finished my laravel, nuxt(ssr,server) project and deployed them separate subdomains like api.example.com && beta.example.com.

In sake of user login when i add `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` to `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file in laravel, all the api get/post requests become so slow or even request throws timeout, but when I directly connect to api url like `https://api.example.com/api/v1/categories` it's shows instantly. Also, at beta subdomain it's comes lightning fast without using `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`.

I am using laravel sanctum and @nuxtjs/proxy module in nuxt like:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    ['@nuxtjs/axios', {
        proxy: true,
        credentials: true,
    }],
    // https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
],
proxy: {
    "/v1/": {
        target: `https://api.example.com/api/v1`,
        pathRewrite: { "^/v1": "" },
        changeOrigin: true
    },
    // and more
    // ...
    // ..
    // .
},
```

**cors.php**

```
  'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'login',
    'logout',
    'register',
    'forgot-password',
    'reset-password',
    'user/password',
    'user/profile-information',
    'email/verify/*',
    'email/verification-notification',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie',
],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

**.env**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=*.example.com
```

Why `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` acting like that? I don't know whats causing such a slowdown... What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```